# How to read a fixed-width file where the width of the last column is variable (ragged) using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, io, fixed-width

I am trying to read a text file that has a fixed-width format, except the last column varies in width, and I don't know what the maximum width will be. It looks something like this:

```
ABC12345DE4G6789Z359782Y
HIJ23456KLMN7891X382W
O8Q34567RSTU8912VU
ABC23456K6MN7891T564556382S
```

and it should be separated into columns like this:

```
C1  C2    C3   C4   C5
ABC 12345 DE4G 6I89 Z359782Y
HIJ 23V56 KLMN 7891 X382W
O8Q 34567 RSTU 89E2 VU
ABC 23456 K6MN 7891 4564556382S
```

Putting a large number as the width of the last column like this:

```
df = pandas.read_fwf('example_data.txt', header=None, names=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'],
    widths=[3, 5, 4, 4, 100])
```

technically works, but I was wondering if a better way existed, like to infer the maximum width of the last column or something.

Comment: to infer the maximum width you would have to read all data from file and this is waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colspecs` parameter.  Not sure this is any better...

```
import io
import pandas as pd
# know col widths
cols = [3, 5, 4, 4]
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO("""ABC12345DE4G6789Z359782Y
HIJ23456KLMN7891X382W
O8Q34567RSTU8912VU
ABC23456K6MN7891T564556382S"""), colspecs=[(sum(cols[:i]),sum(cols[:i+1])) for i in range(len(cols))] + [(sum(cols),None)]
                 , header=None, names=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'])

print(df.to_markdown())
```

|  | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC | 12345 | DE4G | 6789 | Z359782Y |
| 1 | HIJ | 23456 | KLMN | 7891 | X382W |
| 2 | O8Q | 34567 | RSTU | 8912 | VU |
| 3 | ABC | 23456 | K6MN | 7891 | T564556382S |